# Bridgeless suspension forks

Tags: mountain-bike, fork, suspension

Suspension forks typically have a bridge which connects the two lower legs. In the past, this also provided a hanger for the rim brakes. I always thought though that the main purpose was to ensure that the two legs remained parallel in compression, so that there was no torsion on the front axle.

I've noticed some MTB suspension forks that are bridgeless. In these systems what prevents the legs from compressing at different rates and twisting the axle? Can we broadly say a bridgeless suspension is weaker than a bridged one?

[image: rock shox]

Comment: You don't even need 2 legs - Canondale Lefty forks for example, work fine.

Comment: The photo you included looks similar to the fork in http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/42076/upside-down-fork-vs-traditional-fork so the distinction might be inverted vs traditional.

Comment: They will compress at different rates as one has the spring and the other the damper (usually)

Comment: As far as I know the purpose of these bridges was only to increase stiffness for the brakes, and came as an integration of brake boosters into fork design. Horseshoe shaped brake boosters were quite popular in the nineties. Through axles probably make the forks stiffer towards torsion. Example [picture](http://ep1.pinkbike.org/p5pb8288439/p5pb8288439.jpg) of one on a replica re-build of some famous downhill racer's bike.

Comment: @gschenk the brake boosters were primarily to limit flex of the canti brake bosses.  They were always optional.

Comment: @criggie isn't that what I wrote? Clarifying: The inner booster restricts flex of the arms at the bosses outward (arms approaching an O shape). With the addition of the outer booster rotational flex of the bosses about axes along each leg is prevented. Without a rim brake there wouldn't be any momenta at this point in an ideal fork. — Still you got the reliable knowledge, hence only a comment, as I don't expect to be correct.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't broadly say "Bridged suspensions are stronger".  It's depends on many things, including the design of the system, materials used, build quality, etc.

As Batman mentioned, Cannondale's Lefty suspension is stronger than most traditional systems and isn't bridged, or even *bridgeable*.

Inverted, or "upside-down" systems, like the one in your photo, have other considerations as well, outlined in this [question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/42076/upside-down-fork-vs-traditional-fork).  To your question, the thru axel keeps the stanchions bound together, preventing different rates of compression.

I think we will see fewer front forks with suspension bridges in the future and more inverted systems, as the technology trickles out to less expensive builds and the cost of manufacture drops.

Comment: I would think regularly oriented forks will likely stick around as the inverted design is inherently more exposed to scratches on the stanchions. Also weird cable routing.